# Suppress security on localhost connection between Microsoft SQLServer VisualStudio 2022

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

I got the following message

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
> HResult=0x80131904
> Message=A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error     occurred during the login process.
> (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate c    hain was
> issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
> Source=Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider

when establishing a connection to my local Microsoft SQL Server

My connection string is defined in appsettings.json

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=QandA;Trusted_Connection=True;",
    },
   "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
         "Default": "Information",
         "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
      }
   },
   "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

in Program.cs, the following code that use DbUp work

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"); 
EnsureDatabase.For.SqlDatabase(connectionString);
var upgrader = DeployChanges.To
    .SqlDatabase(connectionString, null)
    .WithScriptsEmbeddedInAssembly(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .WithTransaction()
    .Build();
```

The API code call the following function

```
   /// <summary>
   /// Fetch toutes les questions de la BD.
   /// </summary>
   /// <returns>Les questions de la BD.</returns>
   public IEnumerable<QuestionGetManyResponse> GetQuestions()
   {
        // Le using va disposer de la connection automatiquement en quittant le block.
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
               connection.Open();
               return connection.Query<QuestionGetManyResponse>(@"EXEC dbo.Question_GetMany");
            }
   }
```

The _connectionString variable is set in the class constructor. It is properly set when connection.Open() is executed.

How could I remove the security on that connection and why is it working in Program.cs

Comment: At a guess `DeployChanges` is using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient prior to version 4.0, while the main program is using 4.0 or later. [Version 4.0 changed the encryption default from encrypt=false to encrypt=true](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/released-general-availability-of-microsoft-data-sqlclient-4-0/ba-p/2983346). Read the article and determine why this matters and how you want to handle this.

Comment: Hi Always learning you are right, the SqlClient version is 4.1 I add Encrypt=false; in my connection string and it is working. Best regard,

Comment: Instead of disabling encryption add `Trust Server Certificate=True` in the connection string

Answer (score 0):

See comment on my post from Always Learning, I add encrypt=false in the connection string.
That solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).